# I got warning as: "Name 'x' can be undefined" and "Global variable 'x' is undefined at the module level"

Tags: python, global-variables, warnings

I`ve  been working on my code and a few warnings have popped up suach as ***"Name 'x' can be undefined"*** and ***"Global variable 'x' is undefined at the module level"***

Quickly about what a program does:
It can log in the users
It can sigh up a user if there is not a one with this name
A user can withydraw or deposit money to his account

Can anybody quickly go through my code and tell me what the problem is?
And if there is any obvious mistake, please, let me know.
Would be very grateful.

```
users_info = {
    'Bill_Cruz': {
        'age': 45,
        'number': '+248-4052-388',
        'card': '5269-5440-9962-2708',
        'balance': 4321.54,
        'password': 'bill'
    },
    'Robert_Soup': {
        'age': 34,
        'number': '+562-5065-778',
        'card': '4716-7816-7850-1836',
        'balance': 12701,
        'password': 'robertsoup123'
    },
    'Paula_Smith': {
        'age': 41,
        'number': '+231-7307-367',
        'card': '4556-4566-2049-4595',
        'balance': 75.65,
        'password': 'paulasmith123'
    }
}


def name_validation():
    global name, name_edited **### line 27**
    while True:
        name = input('Please give me your name and surname: ').title().strip()
        name_edited = name.replace(" ", "_")
        if name.lower().strip() == "r":
            print('Wellcome to the registration page!')
            new_name = input('I`m gonna need your name and surname: ').title().strip()
            new_name_edited = new_name.strip().replace(" ", "_")
            users_info.update({new_name_edited: {'password': input('Enter a new password: ').strip(),
                                                 'balance': 0}})
            name = new_name
            name_edited = new_name_edited
            break
        elif name_edited not in users_info.keys():
            print('USER NOT FOUND, try again: (r - for signing up)')
            continue
        else:
            break


def log_in():
    attempts = 3
    while True:
        if attempts != 0:
            password = input(f'Please enter your password\n(attempts left - {attempts}): ').strip()
            if password == users_info[name_edited]['password']:
                print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<')
                print('You`ve successfully logged in!')
                break
            else:
                print('The password you`ve entered is incorrect')
                attempts -= 1
                continue
        else:
            print('You have 0 attempts left \nBye')
            quit()
        break


def balance_interaction():
    new_balance = None
    while True:
        print('Would you like to interact?')
        user_action = input('("d" for deposit; "w" for withdrawal; "q" to quit): ')
        if user_action == "d":
            while True:
                try:
                    while True:  # checking if dep ammount is valid
                        deposit = float(input('How much money would you like to deposit?: '))
                        if deposit >= 0:
                            new_balance = users_info[name_edited]['balance'] + deposit
                            break
                        else:
                            print('Cannot ne negative!')
                            continue
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print()
                    print('Enter an amount of money you`d like to deposit!')
                    continue
            break
        elif user_action == "w":
            while True:
                try:
                    while True:
                        withdraw = float(input('How much money would you like to withdraw?: '))
                        if withdraw >= 0:
                            if users_info[name_edited]['balance'] - withdraw >= 0:
                                new_balance = users_info[name_edited]['balance'] - withdraw
                                break
                            else:
                                print(f'Not enough money on the account. '
                                      f'Your available balance is {users_info[name_edited]["balance"]}')
                                continue
                        else:
                            print('Cannot ne negative!')
                            continue
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print()
                    print('Enter an amount of money you`d like to withdraw!')
                    continue
            break
        elif user_action == "q":
            print('Bye!')
            quit()
        else:
            print('Enter something valid!')
            continue
    print(f'Your new available balance is $ {round(new_balance, 2)}')


name_validation()
print(f'Hello, {name}') **### line 120**
log_in()
balance = users_info[name_edited]['balance'] **### line 122**
print(f'Your balance is $ {round(balance, 2)}')
balance_interaction()
```

[There is the screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFDBS.jpg)

Obviously the problem is in globalisation the variables, but I can`t figure out what with exactly.

Comment: I don't see where name is defined outside of the functions.

Comment: You've specified `global name` in a function but `name` is not defined at global level. That is not an error. You are getting a warning because your IDE thinks this might be unintentional. If it's not, ignore the warning. In a dynamic language, warnings based on static analysis can be, and frequently are, offbeam, and sometimes downright wrong. It's important to distinguish between suggestions from your IDE and actual warnings and errors from the Python interpreter. If the interpreter says your code is wrong, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those messages are warning you that the global variables `name` and `name_edited` are defined only by running the `name_validation()` function.  If you hadn't run that function, those variables would not exist.

It's safer practice to define those variables at the top of the module, so they definitely exist in the global scope, without depending on running that function.

Comment: I`ve just added 

name = None
name_edited = None

It`s helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

In this case it is not difficult. Just pass `name` and `name_edited` in and out of functions as needed.

```py
users_info = {
    'Bill_Cruz': {
        'age': 45,
        'number': '+248-4052-388',
        'card': '5269-5440-9962-2708',
        'balance': 4321.54,
        'password': 'bill'
    },
    'Robert_Soup': {
        'age': 34,
        'number': '+562-5065-778',
        'card': '4716-7816-7850-1836',
        'balance': 12701,
        'password': 'robertsoup123'
    },
    'Paula_Smith': {
        'age': 41,
        'number': '+231-7307-367',
        'card': '4556-4566-2049-4595',
        'balance': 75.65,
        'password': 'paulasmith123'
    }
}


def name_validation():
    while True:
        name = input('Please give me your name and surname: ').title().strip()
        name_edited = name.replace(" ", "_")
        if name.lower().strip() == "r":
            print('Wellcome to the registration page!')
            new_name = input('I`m gonna need your name and surname: ').title().strip()
            new_name_edited = new_name.strip().replace(" ", "_")
            users_info.update({new_name_edited: {'password': input('Enter a new password: ').strip(),
                                                 'balance': 0}})
            name = new_name
            name_edited = new_name_edited
        elif name_edited not in users_info.keys():
            print('USER NOT FOUND, try again: (r - for signing up)')
            continue
        return name, name_edited


def log_in(name_edited):
    attempts = 3
    while True:
        if attempts != 0:
            password = input(f'Please enter your password\n(attempts left - {attempts}): ').strip()
            if password == users_info[name_edited]['password']:
                print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<')
                print('You`ve successfully logged in!')
                break
            else:
                print('The password you`ve entered is incorrect')
                attempts -= 1
                continue
        else:
            print('You have 0 attempts left \nBye')
            quit()
        break


def balance_interaction(name_edited):
    new_balance = None
    while True:
        print('Would you like to interact?')
        user_action = input('("d" for deposit; "w" for withdrawal; "q" to quit): ')
        if user_action == "d":
            while True:
                try:
                    while True:  # checking if dep ammount is valid
                        deposit = float(input('How much money would you like to deposit?: '))
                        if deposit >= 0:
                            new_balance = users_info[name_edited]['balance'] + deposit
                            break
                        else:
                            print('Cannot ne negative!')
                            continue
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print()
                    print('Enter an amount of money you`d like to deposit!')
                    continue
            break
        elif user_action == "w":
            while True:
                try:
                    while True:
                        withdraw = float(input('How much money would you like to withdraw?: '))
                        if withdraw >= 0:
                            if users_info[name_edited]['balance'] - withdraw >= 0:
                                new_balance = users_info[name_edited]['balance'] - withdraw
                                break
                            else:
                                print(f'Not enough money on the account. '
                                      f'Your available balance is {users_info[name_edited]["balance"]}')
                                continue
                        else:
                            print('Cannot ne negative!')
                            continue
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print()
                    print('Enter an amount of money you`d like to withdraw!')
                    continue
            break
        elif user_action == "q":
            print('Bye!')
            quit()
        else:
            print('Enter something valid!')
            continue
    print(f'Your new available balance is $ {round(new_balance, 2)}')


name, name_edited = name_validation()
print(f'Hello, {name}')
log_in(name_edited)
balance = users_info[name_edited]['balance']
print(f'Your balance is $ {round(balance, 2)}')
balance_interaction(name_edited)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I didn`t have an idea about how to avoid global

Comment: But bow there are new warning such as: "Shadows name 'name' from outer scope"

Comment: Again that's just a warning, but you can fix that with a trivial renaming: eg. Use `name1` instead of `name` in the last portion of the code.